# Touch scroll contents inside a <div> from outside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

(Please, see the image at the end) I have a `text <div>` on my website, but, it's not full width. The `<body>` of my document doesn't scroll. I just need that `text <div>` to scroll when the user uses the mouse scroll wheel to scroll, but, the mouse pointer is not on my `text <div>`. I found some jQuery code for this purpose. I run this `<script>` on `document.onload`:

Considering the `class` of my `text <div>` is `.scroll`, the following code works:

```
var target = $('.scroll').get(0);
$('body').on('wheel', function (e)
    {
        var o = e.originalEvent;
        target.scrollTop += o.deltaY;
        target.scrollLeft += o.deltaX;
    });
```

So, my problem is, I need to add the same functionality for phones or basically, touch devices. Even if the users touches and scrolls outside my `text <div>`, the `text <div>` should get scrolled. I tried this in the same `<script>` tag, but, didn't work:

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function(e)
    { 
        var o2 = e.originalEvent;
        target.scrollTop += o2.deltaY;
        target.scrollLeft += o2.deltaX;
    });
```

I also tried changing it `.on('tou...` to `.bind('tou...`, both didn't work. The console is also empty. However, if I add `console.log('touched');` in the above code (before the closing `});`, the console does show `touched` in it. So, it might be working, however, the scroll isn't working.

Can someone guide me on how to make this thing work for touch screens? I'm open to other JavaScript-based approaches too.

Image:

[image]

Comment: Can you make a codepen or similar? :)

Comment: @KevinSimper here's it: https://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshk/7ks5ztj8/6/ Sorry for delay.

Comment: @RacilHilan I tried `on('scroll'` now, it doesn't work, probably because the `<body>` doesn't scroll.

Comment: Your jsfiddle is working for me in the browser. Which browser are you having issue with? Never mind the `on('scroll'`, I didn't read your question carefully.

Comment: @RacilHilan Yes, I mentioned that the nomal mouse scroll is working. I'd like the same thing to work on touch based scrolling. I'm using Chrome 77.

Comment: It seems to me touchmove does not have a deltaY/X like wheel has. You would have to get the direction and distance some other way.

Comment: OK, it wasn't clear in your question that the `wheel` worked. For the `touch` event, I'm afraid you'll have to calculate the delta by yourself. Start by getting the first touch `e.touches[0]`, and then get the `pageX` and `pageY` from it. Do that in the `touchstart` and then `touchend` and calculate the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what finally worked for me (this is the entire code, the mouse scroll + touch scroll):

```
var target = $('.scroll').get(0);
$('body').on('wheel', function (e)
    {
        var o = e.originalEvent;
        target.scrollTop += o.deltaY;
    });
var lastTouch = null;
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event)
    {
        lastTouch = event.touches[0];
    })
window.addEventListener('touchend', function (event)
    {
        lastTouch = null;
    })
window.addEventListener('touchmove', function (event)
    {
        var currentTouch = event.changedTouches[0];
        if (lastTouch)
            {
                target.scrollTop += lastTouch.clientY - currentTouch.clientY;
            }
        lastTouch = currentTouch;
    });
```

Comment: I don't know why this has been downvoted. I will counter that with an upvote. It's not the best solution, but it works. The issue with moving in the `touchmove` event is that it can fire rapidly and cause a performance issue. That's why it is usually better to do it in the `touchend` event. But if immediate feedback is more important than the performance, then this approach can be acceptable.

Comment: I check it and work ok but the scroll is not smoothly. What should we do to improve it. I tested on Iphone 11 Safari

Answer (score 0):

This solution using jquery

```js
const $parent = $('.parent')

$parent.on('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
    $parent.animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    })
  } else {
    $parent.animate({
      scrollTop: $parent.prop('scrollHeight')
    })
  }
})
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <h1>first</h1>
  <h1>second</h1>
  <h1>third</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>last</h1>
</div>
```

This is the solution using pure javascript

```js
const $parent = document.querySelector('.parent')

$parent.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    $parent.scrollTo(0, $parent.scrollHeight)
  } else {
    $parent.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }
})
```

```css
.parent {
  height: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>first</h1>
  <h1>second</h1>
  <h1>third</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>content</h1>
  <h1>last</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems, this one is using a button to scroll. I want to use the normal (mousewheel-based) scroll.

Comment: just fire the event wherever you want, i showed you how scroll works

Comment: I tried your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/hrishikeshk/7ks5ztj8/7/ doesn't work. It's just producing some unexpected behaviour in the scrolling of the parent div.

Comment: @HrishikeshKokate you tried it not properly, https://jsfiddle.net/nvbu19ws/

Comment: Ah, well, yeah, got that. But, it still doesn't work on touch.

Comment: same approach, fire event when touched, probably need jqeury touch library

Comment: The code does work, but, it directly takes me to the end or start of the '<div>` even for the smallest of scrolls. It's either the top or the end.

Answer (score 0):

This code might be helpful..

```
$(window).on('touchstart', function(event){
    var currentScrl = event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY;
    var winTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    $(this).on('touchmove', function(event) {
        var scrolling = (event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].clientY - currentScrl)*-1;
        $(this).scrollTop(winTop + scrolling);
    });
});
$(window).on('touchend', function(){
    $(window).off('mousemove');
});
```